# Filter attribute with FOSUserBundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FOSUserBundle with Symfony 2 and MongoDB.
In my user document, there is an EmbedMany relation with a lot of embedded documents

The FOSUserBundle uses a global find to get the logged user:

```
db.user.find({ "_id": ... }).limit(1).limit();
```

So how can I exclude the embedded document from this find ?

Thank you

Comment: Where exactly is that `db.user.find({ "_id": ... }).limit(1).limit();` snippet from? Are you 100% sure that the relation is really being fetched and not lazy-loaded upon first access ?

Comment: The db.user.find() is used to check if a user is logged. I can see it in db queries from the debug bar on each protected page.